# onDeviceReady on hosted pages

Tags: cordova

I have some questions about onDeviceReady event on PhoneGap/Cordova for iOS.

I use it in an application with multiple pages, it works on my index.html and other page link to the same JS file. But I have an other page linked in my app. This page and its script are hosted on my server, in it, onDeviceReady doesn't success and I can't add functions in this part.

I want to know if I need to add this event on each page and if it is working on hosted page, or maybe doesn't works for an other reason.

On my hosted page I use this code :

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false); // Cordova is ready to be used!

function onDeviceReady() {
       DO SOMETHING !
}
});
```

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/libs/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/libs/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script defer src="/js/script.js"></script>
```

I use Cordova 2.1 and test on iPad simulator
I've already added my external site in externalHosts

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

if your you are calling the external pages after (or within) the onDeviceReady() you just make sure you have the local PhoneGap/Cordova reference (on the remote location) and you can the use PhoneGap functions.

for example:

```
function onDeviceReady()
{

    window.location.href = "http://<myRemoteServer>/myRemoteDefault.htm";
}
```

the myRemoteDefault.htm will have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>

<script>
        alert(device.platform);
</script>
```

Comment: If I use this, application open navigator. On my application, I use an HTML link (<a href="my serveur..."></a>). The hosted page is a page of the application. This link works, I can see content in my app, use jQuery, only deviceReady doesn't works.

Comment: are you using PhoneGap with Android? if so try this:                  navigator.app.loadUrl('http://remoteserver/page.htm', { openExternal:false } );